# Error code while trying to change dictionary folder

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I tried to make a simple program that tells me information about an Image. But when i try to change the image folder with os.chdir()

```
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Yonatan\PycharmProjects\Python Programs\Color')
```

i get this error code:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Please help.
~Yonatan Cohen

Comment: use `r'C:\Users\Yonatan\PycharmProjects\Python Programs\Color'` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
r'C:\Users\kallz\Desktop\alice.txt'.
```

That way, everything in the string is interpreted as a literal character, and you don't have to escape every backslash.

That means, r'C:\Users\kallz\Desktop\alice.txt' will evaluate to 'C:\Users\kallz\Desktop\alice.txt'' - without causing the backslash to escape characters.

in your Code

```
from PIL import Image
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Yonatan\PycharmProjects\Python Programs\Color')
```